# Вывод из таблицы одним запросом по разным условиям

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `items`;

```
id --- status
-------------
1  ---   0
2  ---   1
3  ---   1
4  ---   0
5  ---   1
```

Нужно ОДНИМ запросом, вывести кол-во строк со статусом: 0 (их 2) и кол-во строк со стаутсом 1( их 3). Пробовал через UNION - но поля именует не так как нужно.

```
SELECT count(*) AS `status_0` FROM `itemы` WHERE `status` = 0
UNION
SELECT count(*) AS `status_1` FROM `itemы` WHERE `status` = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно получить одну строку с двумя колонками? А две строки с одной колонкой Вас не устраивает. Тогда это делается так

```
SELECT SUM(`status_0`) AS `status_0`, SUM(`status_1`) AS `status_1`
FROM (
  SELECT count(*) AS `status_0`, 0  AS `status_1` FROM `items` WHERE `status` = 0
  UNION
  SELECT 0  AS `status_0`, count(*) AS `status_1` FROM `items` WHERE `status` = 1
)
```

Но я бы делал так

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM items GROUP BY status
```

Comment: 2ой вариант отлично подошел

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case status when 0 then 1 else 0 end) status_0,
sum(case status when 1 then 1 else 0 end) status_1
from items
```

Comment: Тогда уж **select sum(status=0) status_0,
sum(status=1) status_1
from items** CASE-то нафига нужен?

Comment: Потому что этот код будет работать практически под всеми СУБД.

Comment: Зачем? у вопроса тег _MySQL_.

Comment: Я дал решение, которое работает под MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

поля в таблице именуются по первому запросу если я не ошибаюсь, возможно стоит добавить столбец константу 

`SELECT 'status_0', count(*) AS`cnt`FROM`itemы`WHERE`status`= 0
UNION
SELECT 'status_1',count(*) AS`cnt`FROM`itemы`WHERE`status`= 1`

если нужна одна запись

`SELECT  count(*) AS`cnt_0`, c1.cnt_1 
FROM itemы 
Left join (select count(*) AS`cnt_1`from`itemы`where`status`= 1) c1 on 1 = 1
WHERE status = 0`